# Is it possible to run equivalent of a separate thread in Node.js to periodically perform async tasks automatically?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I understand that Node is essentially single threaded, but is there a way to achieve the kind of automated async behaviour that you could achieve in, for example, a Java Spring application by just sparking off a new Thread (or similar)?

My actual requirement is to periodically - *and without prompting from a user event* - iterate through various caches and selectively refresh only the data that has expired. The refresh itself can take some time, so ideally I don't want to wait until the user clicks before it decides to clean up the cache.

Alternatively, if there is a way to achieve this without having to create a completely independent thread, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cluster npm, so it will create multiple thread.

Using cluster it will create co worker

Ref code [click here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use webworkers threads API of JS to implement this functionalty. Refer to the npm package for more information [webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads)